# work out percentages in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to run a query in PHP that selects data from a database and works out percentages

```
$vattotal=0;
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from adhocbills_lineitems where bill_seq = :bill_seq ");
$stmt->execute(array(':bill_seq' => $_GET["seq"]));
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($records as $VatResult) {
    $vattotal = $vattotal + $VatResult["unitprice"]*$VatResult["vat"];
}
```

i want to work out the `unitprice` column times the `vat` column

`unitprice` is a price value and `vat` is a percentage value

so say, `unitprice = 225` and `vat = 20` i want it to show 225 times 20%

but at the moment it is just doing `225*20` which is 4500

Comment: `($VatResult["unitprice"]/100)*$VatResult["vat"]` ?

Comment: please mind working with VAT is tricky, you need to store **at least** both NETTO and BRUTTO or NETTO and VAT or BRUTTO and VAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `$VatResult["vat"]`, which is a value between 0 and 100, to a value between 0 and 1.  Simple divide it by 100 at the appropriate point; i.e. `$VatResult["vat"] / 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to calculate 20% of 225 you should be multiplying `unitprice` by 0.2 not 20.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$vattotal = $vattotal + $VatResult["unitprice"]*$VatResult["vat"]/100;
```